# Poor WCF performance when running on a VM

Tags: wcf, vmware, performance

I'm working on a self-hosted WCF application which runs just fine on my PC; however, when I try running it on a VM hosted locally using VMware Player, the service takes some two minutes to return data, whereas the original request took only a few seconds.

The VM is using 2Gb RAM and dual CPU running Windows Server 2008 R2 (on an 8Gb/quad core host running Windows 7).

Looking at the WCF service trace, I have the following log entries (time/description):

```
15:41:26.771 From: Processing message 1.
15:41:26.771 Activity boundary.
15:41:26.820 Received a message over a channel.
15:41:26.844 ServiceChannel information.
15:41:26.848 Incoming HTTP request to URI 'http://localhost:8000/Sql/Database' matched operation 'GetDatabase'
15:41:26.944 Message Log Trace
15:43:25.775 To: Execute 'MyProject.ISqlService.GetDatabase'
15:43:25.775 Activity boundary.
15:43:25.947 From: Execute 'MyProject.ISqlService.GetDatabase'
15:43:25.947 Activity boundary.
15:43:25.947 Message Log Trace
15:43:26.134 Throwing an exception.
15:43:26.134 RequestContext aborted
15:43:26.134 Activity boundary.
```

So the two minute delay occurs between receiving the incoming HTTP request and the dispatch to the service implementation. This delays occurs whether the request is the first (thus incurring the usual WCF warm-up penalty) or a subsequent request.

While I appreciate that I'm not going to get bare-metal performance from a VM, I'm still concerned about the dire performance, especially as the client tends to timeout before the end of the two minutes. Is there anything I can do to improve matters? It's making testing very difficult.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem with this? I am running into a very similar issue with virtual box.

Comment: Sorry, no; in the end I stopped using the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your proc does not support VT-x/AMD-V extension, so virtualization is not hardware-accelerated. Check your hardware using CPU-Z.

Comment: I installed CPU-Z as you suggest, and it reports that the CPU is an Intel Core 2 Quad Q9400 @ 2.66GHz, and that the following instructions are enabled: MMX, SSE (1, 2, 3, 3S, 4.1), EM64T, VT-x; so I don't think that's the specific problem.